# htaccess redirect http/www and https/www to https/nonwww

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I tried every single solution I found on the web but my issue doesn't seem to be working. I've got an SSL-cerificate for a non-www domain. So I try to redirect the traffic to the non-www domain with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The issue is:

```
http://example.com -> https://example.com WORKS
https://example.com -> https://example.com WORKS
http://www.example.com -> https://example.com WORKS
https://www.example.com -> https://example.com DOESN'T WORK
```

I desperately looking for help and appreciate any hint. The next Issue is that it seems only not to work in FireFox but in Chrome it works like a charm! I deleted the cache in FireFox before every reload. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you actually mean by "doesn't work" _exactly_? I suspect you refer to the fact that `https://www.example.com` throws a client side warning and refuses to connect, not that you have an issue with the actual rewriting. Please note that without a valid ssl certificate for `www.example.com` there is absolutely nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes this exactly what I want. So there is no way to redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com without a certificate?

Comment: No, obviously not. Think about what you ask: the client has to send a request to the host `www.example.com` initially _and ultimately trust the information received as a response_. That is the reason that the validity of certificates are checked _before_ anything else happens with an established connection. That is the whole point of https certificate verification. The fact that you "only" want to redirect is irrelevant in this.

Comment: But what is the problem with creating a valid certificate for that host name? It is for free these days...